# Time.now in activerecord format

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I need it for an unit test... how to get a time.now in the same format as active record returns for a datetime field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

The UTC is probably added by Rails itself. Have you checked at your database console how exactly is stored the date?

Anyway, a shorter way to do the above is `Time.now.to_s(:db)`, but what you're probably looking for is `Time.now.to_formatted_s :rfc822` (Documentation [here](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0RC/classes/Time.html#M003244))